# Runtime error: Access violation when using .push_back() with a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, directx

I have a vector, defined by `std::vector<LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9> textures;`  Later, I am passing a `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` object to it, like so `textures.push_back(texture);`  Here is a sample of this:

```
void SpriteManager::AddSprite(float x, float y, float z, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture)
{
    //snip
    textures.push_back(texture);
    //snip
}
```

This is causing a runtime error.  It is breaking in the vector class at the `size()` function.  Why might this happen?

**Edit:**

I also run into an identical problem performing the same operation on a vector of `D3DXVECTOR3` objects.  Since `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` is a pointer to an `IDIRECT3DTEXTURE9`, should I be using that instead?

Comment: Are you sure that's all you do? Have you tried to compile a simplified version of your problem?

Maybe your real problem is the slicing problem (if you are using inheritance somehow)

Comment: The slicing problem?  Nothing is inheriting from vector.  This code compiled and ran fine before I added this vector, yes.

Comment: Nevermind, slicing problem only happens when you have a vector of objets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most common reason is that you actually don't have a vector. In this case, `textures` appears to be a member of the `SpriteManager` class. So, that suggest you actually don't have a `SpriteManager` object either. Is the `this` pointer valid?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 by its Hungarian name is a pointer and not an object (as you refer to it), my guess is that you are passing around invalid pointers which have already done a [fandango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fandango_on_core) on your poor vector object before you call push_back().

I might be wrong, but this is as much as can be said from the information you provide. And, yes, push_back() should only be able to fail if you are out of memory or trying to use a non-copyable or non-assignable object in the vector, and then not through an access violation.

Comment: a vector of pointers does not care that the pointers it holds are invalid.

Comment: Nope. But if pointers and objects are confused, I'd start looking for invalid pointers somewhere around, as you also are suggesting.

Comment: This is interesting.  However, nothing happens to the pointer beforehand.  I create the texture pointer, which I know is valid, and pass it to the function to use .push_back().  Nothing else happens to it along the way.

Comment: I doubt this is the answer whether the pointer is invalid or not will not cause an access violation as push_back does not write through to the item being stored.

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems you are mangling the vector somewhere, whether through the stored pointers or something else. I just got suspicious when you called a pointer an object... Try changing the location of the textures vector (a member of SpriteManager?) by e.g. adding dummy char[512] data structures around it and see whether you get the same error in the same place.

Comment: -1, this is a Windows environment from the name. Hence, we know that `std::vector<T*>` doesn't care about bad T*'s.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector has been corrupted. I'd suggest putting a data watchpoint on its internals to see what is stomping on it (in a debugger).